# How can I separate CSS elements and values using regex?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have CSS file and want to separate elements and values in form fields to make it editable using regular expressions.

This is my CSS:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="css">
    .input-block-level {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 30px;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
         -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
              box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    ##map_canvas img,
    .google-maps img {
      /*edit*/max-width: none;
    }

    #sup {
      position: relative;
      font-size: 75%;
      line-height: 0;
      vertical-align: baseline;
    }
</cfsavecontent>
```

I have tried the expression below to extract the elements between the opening and closing braces. It works fine but I am wondering how to get elements and values delimited by lines.

```
<cfset reg1 = REMatch("{(?i)(.+?)}",css) />
<cfdump var="#reg1#" label="braces">
```

How can I write a regex pattern to separate the elements and values? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to demonstrate you've actually attempted to solve this yourself, otherwise it seems like you're just asking us to do your work for you. What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Sorry for that, now i have updated.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to put css into a form field and ask the user to edit it?  Where is the css coming from in the first place?

Comment: I am having one file which wrapped with cfsavecontent then i would like to use regex stuff to get the elements and their values in the form fields.

Comment: _Huh?_ I don't understand what you're doing or explaining, but there's a good chance you're doing it wrong - you should really look for a CSS parser (pretty sure Ben Nadel did one in CF).

Comment: @PeterBoughton - will you please give me the link.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ben+nadel+css+parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me to split up the items and values, not sure it's exactly what you're needing though:

```
<cfset reg1 = REMatch("{(?i)(.+?)}",css) />

<cfloop index="item" array="#reg1#">    
    <cfset lines = listToArray(item, Chr(10))>

    <cfloop index="line" array="#lines#">
        <cfset arrLine = listToArray(line, ":")>

        <cfif arrayLen(arrLine) EQ 2>
            <cfset item = trim(arrLine[1])>
            <cfset value = trim(arrLine[2])>
            <cfoutput>
                item: #item#<br>
                value: #value#<br>
                <br>
            </cfoutput>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: I don't know why i am getting opening and closing braces with each elements and values. i would to like to have **elements = 'element' and values = 'value'**.